# spring thymeleaf : call specific tab

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

On users.html, there is the main and industries tab.
When I load users.html I want industries tab to load. how do I do it?

```
<div class='tabs-x tabs-above tabs-krajee'>
    <ul id="myTab-tabs-above" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#home-tabs" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Main</a></li>
        <li><a href="#users-tabs" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Industries</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Tab content refers to this part -->
    <div id="tabs-content" class="tab-content">
        <div id="home-tabs" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <div th:include="fragments/admin/companyProfile::companyProfile(${currentAccountant})"></div>
        </div>

         <div id="users-tabs" class="tab-pane fade">
             <div th:include="fragments/admin/users::users">a</div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Following code loads userDetails but I want a specific tab to be selected on loading. How do I do it?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/load", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView load() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("userDetails");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Comment: where you specify which tab to select? In spring controller/html?

Comment: I have not specified. I want to specify. how do i do it ?      When my controlled does  modelAndView.setViewName("userDetails");, how do i say call users-tabs from userDetails ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger tab show on document load.

Check [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_tab.asp)

```
<div class='tabs-x tabs-above tabs-krajee'>
    <ul id="myTab-tabs-above" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#home-tabs" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Main</a></li>
        <li><a href="#users-tabs" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Industries</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Tab content refers to this part -->
    <div id="tabs-content" class="tab-content">
        <div id="home-tabs" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <div th:include="fragments/admin/companyProfile::companyProfile(${currentAccountant})"></div>
        </div>

         <div id="users-tabs" class="tab-pane fade">
             <div th:include="fragments/admin/users::users">a</div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script th:inline="javascript">
    var tabToSelect = "users-tabs";
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myTab-tabs-above a[href="#'+tabToSelect+'"]').tab('show')
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not specified that which tab to select. How do you want to separate the logic for adding Main and industries.
In Controller
if you want to show MainTab

```
modelAndView.addObject("mainTabAddOrNot","show");
```

otherwise

```
 modelAndView.addObject("mainTabAddOrNot",null);
```

In Thymeleaf side:

```
<li th:if="$(mainTabAddOrNot)" >
     <a href="#home-tabs" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Main</a></li>
    <li><a href="#users-tabs" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Industries</a></li>
```

It is just an example to give an idea to use conditions in thymeleaf for specific tag adding. Hope it will give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to change your controller code neither javascript. Just set your tab  **active** .
 Also you must set the Industries tab **active**.

```html
<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" data-toggle="list" href="#industries"
                       role="tab">
                        Industries Tab Data
 </a>
 
 
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="industries" role="tabpanel">
```